# Cannot use variable inside json --data

Tags: json, bash, curl, linode

I have a working API (linode) to update a domain. So, below is a normal API call that work just fine to update data:

```
  #!/bin/bash

  # hardcoded data for testing
  LINODE_API_KEY=1234
  domain_id=1931316
  domain_name="abx.com"
  domain_type="master"
  domain_email="hello@abx.com"
  domain_ttl=30

  
  # Update the domain
  curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${LINODE_API_KEY}" \
  -X PUT -d "{

  \"domain\": \"${domain_name}\", \"type\": \"${domain_type}\", \"soa_email\": \"${domain_email}\", \"ttl_sec\": ${domain_ttl}
  
  }" "https://api.linode.com/v4/domains/${domain_id}"
```

When I executed the above update API, it's working fine and I get the json response as:

```
{"id": 1931316, "type": "master", "domain": "abx.com", "tags": [], "group": "", "status": "active", "errors": "", "description": "", "soa_email": "hello@abx.com", "retry_sec": 0, "master_ips": [], "axfr_ips": [], "expire_sec": 0, "refresh_sec": 0, "ttl_sec": 30, "created": "2022-12-13T09:01:01", "updated": "2022-12-14T03:26:27"}
```

But the problem is I want to use variable inside the data. So I change the working code above into this (with extra data that I want to pass):

```
  #!/bin/bash
  # hardcoded data for testing
  LINODE_API_KEY=1234
  domain_id=1931316
  domain_name="abx.com"
  domain_type="master"
  domain_email="hello@abx.com"
  domain_ttl=30
  
  # This value must be provided first
  if [ -z "${domain_name}" ]; then
     echo "You must provide domain name"
     exit 1
  else
     change_domain_name="\\\"domain\\\": \\\"${domain_name}\\\""
  fi      

  if [ -n "${domain_type}" ]; then
     change_domain_type=", \\\"type\\\": \\\"${domain_type}\\\""
  else
     change_domain_type=""
  fi

  if [ -n "${soa_email}" ]; then
     change_domain_email=", \\\"soa_email\\\": \\\"${domain_email}\\\""
  else
     change_domain_email=""
  fi

  if [ -n "${domain_ttl}" ]; then
     change_domain_ttl=", \\\"ttl_sec\\\": ${domain_ttl}"
  else
     change_domain_ttl=""
  fi
  update_string="${change_domain_name}${change_domain_type}${change_domain_email}${change_domain_ttl}"

  # Update the domain
  curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${LINODE_API_KEY}" \
  -X PUT -d "{

  ${update_string} # THE PROBLEM IS HERE WHEN USING THIS VARIABLE
  
  }" "https://api.linode.com/v4/domains/${domain_id}"
```

The API will complain about Invalid JSON

```
{"errors": [{"reason": "Invalid JSON"}]}
```

But when I use `echo ${update_string}` variable, I will get the same data syntax like I use so why does it complain this is invalid?

I can even copy paste back the echo result above inside the -d data and it's working fine.

I rolled back my question to the original as to explain why I use the above method instead of creating `jq --arg` as suggested @Arnaud Valmary.

So for example here I only want to pass value domain_name and domain_ttl. So the value of the update string would be like this:

update_string="${change_domain_name}${change_domain_ttl}"

where the others were empty. So, I'm not sure how to achieve this using `jq --arg`

In brief, if domain_type="" or domain_type is empty, I don't want this variable to be in the --arg options, so user have a choice not to update this value.

Comment: Too many backslashes. You need only one per each double quote

Comment: @oguzismail which one are u referring, Is it this one ? -> `change_domain_name="\\\"domain\\\": \\\"${domain_name}\\\""` The extra double slash there means I need one slash more. So it has the same sequence data like previous one. I'm not sure what else to put if I need to make it the same data sequence like previous one. Can you explain what was the issue ?

Comment: I edited my question and simplify the code

Comment: I always use `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` but I never use bash string construction to build JSON data. Use `jq` tool to format your data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to build JSON data with a dedicated tool like `jq`. Bash string construction is hazardous.

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# hardcoded data for testing
declare LINODE_API_KEY=1234
declare domain_id=1931316
declare domain_name="abx.com"
declare domain_type="master"
declare domain_email="hello@abx.com"
declare domain_ttl=30

declare json_query_data='{}'
# This value must be provided first
if [ -z "${domain_name}" ]; then
    echo "You must provide domain name"
    exit 1
else
    # shellcheck disable=SC2016
    json_query_data=$(jq --arg domain "${domain_name}" '.domain |= $domain' <<<"${json_query_data}")
fi

if [ -n "${domain_type}" ]; then
    # shellcheck disable=SC2016
    json_query_data=$(jq --arg type "${domain_type}" '.type |= $type' <<<"${json_query_data}")
fi

if [ -n "${domain_email}" ]; then
    # shellcheck disable=SC2016
    json_query_data=$(jq --arg soa_email "${domain_email}" '.soa_email |= $soa_email' <<<"${json_query_data}")
fi

if [ -n "${domain_ttl}" ]; then
    # shellcheck disable=SC2016
    json_query_data=$(jq --argjson ttl_sec "${domain_ttl}" '.ttl_sec |= $ttl_sec' <<<"${json_query_data}")
fi

# Update the domain
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer ${LINODE_API_KEY}" \
    -X PUT \
    -d "${json_query_data}" \
    --url "https://api.linode.com/v4/domains/${domain_id}"
```

cURL command is:

```bash
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer 1234' -X PUT -d '{"domain":"abx.com","type":"master","soa_email":"hello@abx.com","ttl_sec":30}' --url 'https://api.linode.com/v4/domains/1931316'
```

Comment: I realized that I cannot use this solution because, if I have another variable domain_type , this variable can sometimes be empty. I accidentally simplified my question and it was out from what I wanted. I will redo my question to the original. The original question explained what I wanted. I will redo it.

Comment: I undo my question to the original that explained about this.

Comment: U have typo at the end but I still get invalid Json ^_^

Comment: typo fixed. how it's invalid?

Comment: Ok, it's working but does not seems like what I want. Problem is that I want to construct the data string dynamically based on the data from variable. For example both of these are empty `domain_type=""` and `domain_email=""` then in the `json_query_format` I dont want to include those 2 variables plus inside `json_query_data=` So the curl command only update `domain_name` and `domain_ttl` variable (this is what I'm asking from the first post with my example code). You can see my `$update_string` variable is the one that handle the data string dynamically.

Comment: @KalibZen, it's only "fine" until you have a variable that doesn't substitute cleanly into JSON without escaping. A value with a tab, a backslash, with literal quotes, etc won't work without a tool like jq that understands JSON syntax. And if the linode API you're calling has more powerful capabilities you don't want this script to access, then the ability to use hostile values to escape from the original context can even become a security concern.

Comment: @KalibZen, anyhow, it's trivial to have jq filter out empty elements (so that keys with a value of `""` aren't included in the output at all), though the fact that your question doesn't ask how to do so makes requiring an answer to demonstrate the practice before it's accepted questionable.

Comment: How can u show empty elements? I thought the --arg option need to have key + value.

Comment: @KalibZen, yes, `--arg` does need to have a value, but that doesn't mean you need to write your jq code to _include_ an empty value if it's there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250421/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-kalib-zen).

Comment: update with optional fields construction

Comment: Hello @ArnaudValmary thank you so much.. but I have a question about the 3rd argument eg: `'.type |= $type'` what does the statement means ? How exactly does it gets empty string if value is not passed.

Comment: This `jq` syntax add/update to the root object (mark with dot `.`) a field named `type` with the value of `type` parameter. This syntax is useful to add any type of value. The bash `if` test before `jq` is used to not execute it. More doc about `jq`: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/   Play with `jq` syntax: https://jqplay.org/

Answer (score 1):

This is an error-prone endeavor. You're better off using a JSON-parser like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) to build your JSON data:

```
$ xidel -s \
  --variable name="$domain_name" \
  --variable type="$domain_type" \
  --variable email="$domain_email" \
  --variable ttl="$domain_ttl" \
  -e '{
    "domain":$name,
    "type"?:if ($type="") then () else $type,
    "soa_email"?:if ($email="") then () else $email,
    "ttl_sec"?:if ($ttl="") then () else int($ttl)
  }'
{
  "domain": "abx.com",
  "type": "master",
  "soa_email": "hello@abx.com",
  "ttl_sec": 30
}
```

If only `$domain_name` was declared, then in this case only `{"domain": "abx.com"}` would be returned.

### Curl

Generate the (serialized) JSON data with `xidel`, export as a variable and execute `curl` with it:

```
#!/bin/bash
LINODE_API_KEY=1234
domain_id=1931316
domain_name="abx.com"
domain_type="master"
domain_email="hello@abx.com"
domain_ttl=30

if [ -z "${domain_name}" ]; then
   echo "You must provide domain name"
   exit 1
fi

eval "$(
  xidel -s \
  --variable name="$domain_name" \
  --variable type="$domain_type" \
  --variable email="$domain_email" \
  --variable ttl="$domain_ttl" \
  -e '
    json_query_data:=serialize(
      {
        "domain"?:$name,
        "type"?:if ($type="") then () else $type,
        "soa_email"?:if ($email="") then () else $email,
        "ttl_sec"?:if ($ttl="") then () else int($ttl)
      },
      {"method":"json"}
    )
  ' --output-format=bash
)"

curl \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ${LINODE_API_KEY}" \
-X PUT \
-d "${json_query_data}" \
--url "https://api.linode.com/v4/domains/${domain_id}"
```

### Xidel

Generate *and* send the JSON data *and* parse the returning JSON data with `xidel` (making `curl` superfluous):

```
#!/bin/bash
LINODE_API_KEY=1234
domain_id=1931316
domain_name="abx.com"
domain_type="master"
domain_email="hello@abx.com"
domain_ttl=30
  
# This value must be provided first
if [ -z "${domain_name}" ]; then
   echo "You must provide domain name"
   exit 1
fi

xidel -s \
--variable name="$domain_name" \
--variable type="$domain_type" \
--variable email="$domain_email" \
--variable ttl="$domain_ttl" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ${LINODE_API_KEY}" \
--method PUT \
-d '{
  serialize(
    {
      "domain"?:$name,
      "type"?:if ($type="") then () else $type,
      "soa_email"?:if ($email="") then () else $email,
      "ttl_sec"?:if ($ttl="") then () else int($ttl)
    },
    {"method":"json"}
  )
}' \
"https://api.linode.com/v4/domains/${domain_id}" \
-e '$json'
```